# Installing CentOS 8 on HP Desktop

Tags: centos

I purchased a HP ENVY TE01-1134 Desktop. It came preinstalled with Windows. Windows works perfectly fine on it. I downloaded CentOS ISO and created bootable USB with BalenaEtcher. I rebooted the computer and it booted Windows 10 immediately, bypassing the bootable USB.

Is there a way to find out if HP ENVY TE01-1134 Desktop specs will suffice for CentOS? https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c06783793 (Intel i7 10th Generation, 16 GB DDR4-2933 SDRAM, 512 GB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD, Intel® UHD Graphics 630).

I am preparing for the Red Hat exam and I want to install CentOS directly on the Computer, not through VirtualBox. Also, I want to preserve the existing Windows 10 on it, therefore requiring partition creation.

Before I launch the BIOS and attempt this, I want to have some degree of confidence that this is possible. Again, is there a way to find out if HP ENVY TE01-1134 Desktop specs will suffice for CentOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS will run absolutely fine in those specs. I run it in an almost identical environment (Intel i5 10th gen, 16Gb RAM, 512GB ssd and UHD graphics + Discrete Nvidia RTX 2060.

So you can have an idea, I have AlmaLinux 8.4 (Centos 8.4) running on a 13 year old laptop and works great as a test server.

If you have problems with the USB install, try burning in DD mode instead of ISO. I use Rufus for the USB creation.

Comment: It was so easy! I simply repartitioned C on Windows 10, then created a bootable USB, then opened up Boot menu, selected Boot from USB, then it booted CentOS Installer, I selected the new empty partition and it installed on it, thus preserving the Windows Boot and the new CentOS boot on startup.